# Excepciones al cierre por "un error tipográfico"

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

La pregunta [Error en COUNT() en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/43963/127) (2K+) fue eliminada por ser un error tipográfico (-es correcto, era un error tipográfico).

**Pregunta**

[image: captura de pregunta]

**Respuesta**

[image: captura de la respuesta que muestra que tiene un espacio de más]

---

No obstante, me pregunto si no deberíamos hacer una excepción en estos casos. Puntualmente, la pregunta:

- Está bien formulada, con un buen título, y tiene el código mínimo, completo y **verificable** (no nos confundamos "*calidad*" con "*dificultad del problema*").
- Tiene **el texto del error** específico del problema.
- El texto del error es **exclusivo** de este problema.
- Es genérico y se puede reproducir.
- Claramente tiene una respuesta única, no basada en opiniones.

Pensando en que el error puede ser algo que le ocurra a cualquier programador, y que decida buscarlo en Google con ese mismo texto, creería que es un caso que pudiera atraer a nuevos visitantes al sitio.

¿No deberíamos hacer una excepción en estos casos, y sólo en estos casos?

---

<sub>Nota: el objetivo de la pregunta apunta a seguir generando una base de conocimientos en español. Si hay una pregunta idéntica abierta o cerrada en SOen, los invito a ignorarla, y así generar nuestras propias reglas</sub>

Comment: Si la pregunta es mala, debe cerrarse. Si no está cerrada y tiene respuestas y muestra aceptación de la comunidad pero es un mal ejemplo, lo mejor es borrarla. Lo primordial es mantener la calidad del sitio y de sus publicaciones. La "reputación perdida" no debería ser problema, porque estamos en el sitio para apoyar por sobre ganar reputación.

Comment: @Luiggi Creo que la pregunta no es mala. De hecho, un punto importante que expreso en la publicación es que es una pregunta que puede sumarle calidad al sitio, en el sentido de que es un texto de error que se puede buscar en Google y que atraería a nuevos visitantes. No me parece un mal ejemplo. La pregunta está bien formulada. En cuanto a la reputación perdida, no está relacionado a la pregunta (de hecho yo no participé ni en la pregunta ni en la respuesta).

Comment: @Luiggi tampoco estoy cuestionando el hecho de que la hayas eliminado. Creo que hiciste perfecto, ya que esa es la política actual. Estoy invitando a la comunidad a discutir si no deberíamos agregar una excepción en la política de "error tipográfico".

Comment: Mi opinión sigue siendo la misma.

Comment: En ese caso espero tu -1 ;-) - [*meta is murder*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/)

Comment: En caso de que sea un error tipográfico, eso se podría reproducir de todos modos, y debería salir algún error evidente, el cual se podría haber solucionado, tal como lo hicieron en la respuesta. Parece una buena pregunta.

Comment: Coincido con @Mariano. Entiendo por `error tipográfico` algo como un *baile de caracteres*. La pregunta en cuestión se origina por el *desconocimiento* del autor sobre si los espacios son o no significativos, algo común si se tiene poca experiencia con lenguajes en general y con el indicado en particular. Esa pregunta merece ser *indultada*.

Comment: @Trauma también puedo hacer una pregunta muy bien elaborada y documentada con el stacktrace que arroja el compilador si me faltase un `;` al final de una sentencia. Sigue siendo una pregunta por desconocimiento, por poca experiencia... por un error tipográfico.

Comment: Creo que el principal problema es poder definir "error tipográfico". Tal vez equivocarte en un caracter o que falte un ";" sea un error de ese tipo, pero cuando no son conocidas por el usuario ciertas reglas especificas del lenguaje creo que no puede ser un error tipográfico.

Comment: @ReneLimon es un espacio antes del paréntesis. Eso es un error tipográfico. Es como decir "por qué no funciona `console.lgo("contenido de mi variable " + var);`" y poner una respuesta diciendo "es `console.log`, no `console.lgo`". Es similar, cae en la misma categoría. Es un error tipográfico.

Comment: @Luiggi recién publicaron una respuesta más alineada con mi opinión. -Te comento en caso de que te interese exponer tu punto de vista.

Comment: Si, pero el texto en la versión inglesa es mas específico porque pone *"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"* mientras que en la versión española pusieron *"Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos."*. Me parece mas claro decir que *"fue causado por"*, en lugar de *"que contiene"*. ç

Answer (score 3):

Un error tipográfico es cuando sabes que se escribe `console.log` y es eso lo que querías escribir pero te equivocas al pulsar las teclas y escribes `console.lgo`. La persona que pregunta ya sabía la respuesta antes de preguntar, no es un problema de falta de conocimiento, sino que es un error de tipografía.

No es un error tipográfico si has escrito bien `console.log` pero has cambiado de la versión de CodePluseitor 2.0 a CodePluseitor 4.4 y resulta que han eliminado esa función del todo, ahora has de usar `console.log4`. Aquí no hay error tipográfico, no dejaste de pulsar el 4 por error, sino que hay desconocimiento de ciertos cambios que se han producido en la nueva version; un buen caso para preguntar.

¿A cual de los dos caso pertenece la pregunta en cuestión?

Hay dos indicios:

- Si fuese un error tipográfico entonces el problema sería la pulsación accidental de la barra espaciadora. Pero en la pregunta ese error aparece **dos** veces, tanto en el SELECT como en el HAVING hay un espacio tras el count. Esto indica que no fue un error al pulsar las teclas (error tipográfico). El autor escribió eso a propósito pues pensaba que era la forma correcta de hacerlo.
- Hay muchos lenguajes en que es aceptable poner espacios después de nombres de función o palabras claves. Es posible que por desconocimiento y por la inercia de otros lenguajes el autor pensase que esta era la forma correcta de hacerlo. En este caso la respuesta sería explicar la parte del lenguaje relevante, que sí es algo que entra en el ámbito de este sitio.

Conclusión : Era una buena pregunta. No era un error tipográfico. Las respuestas llevarán al autor a decirse "Anda!, pues no sabía que el lenguaje es así", en vez de a decirse "Si eso ya lo sabía! Es que pulse las teclas mal por error".

En cuanto a los errores tipográficos de verdad, no, no creo que debiera haber excepciones. Que te ayuden a darte cuenta que pulsaste mal las teclas no va a servir de ayuda a otros.