# Como reportar Usuarios que bloquean por maldad?

Tags: soporte, convenciones-sociales, código-de-conducta

Es mas que obvio que si supiera no molesto a nadie pero ya van varias veces que parece que estos tres seres **sstan, Mariano, Muriano** me tienen mis preguntas en espera en https://es.stackoverflow.com/ ¿Como puedo reportar estos tres usuarios? se nota su mala intención es mas que obvio que si yo tuviera alguna idea de como realizar la pregunta tuviera la respuesta para realizar dicha actividad.

¿Y cómo saco su id de usuario, alguna guía?

Comment: Ten en que puede que esos usuarios no te estén acosando, sino votando desde las colas de revisión.

Comment: Puedes obtener el perfil de usuario con ir a su perfil. En la url aparece su id.

Comment: Voy a revisar algunas de las preguntas que indicas para comprobar qué sucede.

Comment: Si alvaro es que pusieron algunas de mi preguntas en espera SIN motivo aparente y no me parece justo me pongan en estado de espera un tal mariano y muriano que por cierto deben ser la misma persona reportando mis preguntas ya tengo tiempo viendo sus intenciones la verdad que la gente buena hace este mundo cada vez mejor, este foro me encanta yo trato de ser lo mas especifico que puedo pero por ignorante no puedo a veces mejorar mis preguntas trato de explicarme lo mejor que puedo, a ver un ejemplo que el del chico de AJAX pudo responder antes de ponerme en espera.

Comment: No voy a poner las manos en el fuego para nadie... pero te puedo decir que al menos _sstan_ y _mariano_ son usuarios ya establecidos, y dudo mucho que lo hagan por maldad o algo parecido. Ahora, que hayan votado para cerrar la pregunta y uno se siente molesto, pues me imagino que si, pero he mirado algunas de tus preguntas y la verdad es que le falta algo más de información, para que los usuarios de la comunidad te puedan ayudar adecuadamente.

Comment: Recuerda que este sito no es un foro...es un  sitio de preguntas y respuestas...  ademas he visto que no tienes la medalla: `Informado` quizás deberías pasarte por [el tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) & [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) ... y verás como todo mejorara.

Comment: Hola Juan. Lo siento por el malentendido. Si te refieres a [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45055/relog-regresivo-a-partir-de-consulta-de-un-select), en efecto voté para poner en espera, no por maldad, sino debido a que 1) sinceramente no me parece clara la pregunta, y 2) porque ya habías hecho exactamente la misma pregunta que quedó puesto en espera, y en la cual se te dejó comentarios especificando los detalles que faltaban para aclarar la pregunta. Pero en vez de aclarar la pregunta, simplemente la borrastes y volvistes a abrir la misma pregunta sin ninguna mejora.

Comment: Y solo agregaría que, al menos en cuanto a Mariano se refiere, mi observación hasta ahora ha sido que, donde a veces yo fallo en ser paciente o mantener un tono positivo, él, en contraste, siempre ha demostrado ser extremadamente razonable, paciente y dispuesto a ayudar a los usuarios que les cuesta formular buenas preguntas. Él sería la última persona que te daría un voto negativo por maldad, eso te lo puedo asegurar.

Comment: He estado revisando lo que comentas y sinceramente no veo argumentos para acusar a otros usuarios de identidades falsas ni comportamiento abusivo hacia otros. En cambio sí que me he dado cuenta (y he eliminado) varios comentarios agresivos por tu parte. Creo que es genial que lo lleves en meta pero creo que es importante mantener los modales, ser imparciales y sobretodo **respetuosos**. Asimismo tienes razón en que como comunidad tenemos que mejorar nuestra interacción con los nuevos usuarios, Estamos en proceso :)

Answer (score 16):

Realmente lamento que te lo hayas tomado como algo personal. Para ser sincero, al votar para cerrar esas preguntas, yo ni siquiera relacioné que eran del mismo usuario, ni tengo muy claro el historial de tus publicaciones. Y estoy publicando algo que no debería publicar, con el riesgo de que lo sigas tomando como personal. Mi intención, te aseguro, es poder explicarte lo que pensé al votar en esas preguntas.

> Es mas que obvio que si supiera no molesto a nadie

Al contrario, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Como tal, las preguntas le dan vida a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Espero que puedas seguir publicando todas las preguntas que se te ocurran.

> Ya van varias veces que parece que estos tres seres sstan, Mariano, Muriano me tienen mis preguntas en espera

Para cerrar una pregunta se necesita el voto de 5 personas. Yo soy un usuario que le dedica mucho tiempo a la revisión de preguntas, y aparezco entre los que más revisiones hicieron, por lo que termino votando (a favor o en contra) en la gran mayoría de éstas. El hecho de que veas mi nombre seguido como votante es algo normal y se repite en muchas de las preguntas del sitio. Llevo emitidos 726 votos de cierre.

> ¿Como puedo reportar estos tres usuarios?

Publicando en [Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/), como hiciste, es una de las formas posibles. [Luiggi Mendoza♦](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza) es [moderador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) del sitio (por eso el diamante) y, como te comentó, tomó tu reporte y evaluará las acciones.

No obstante, muchas veces es preferible que no sea público (por ejemplo, que no quieras que *yo* vea tu reporte). En ese caso, y por lo general siempre se recomienda, se puede enviar un reporte personalizado sobre alguna publicación o algún comentario.

Por ejemplo, en este caso, podrías haber elegido cualquiera de tus preguntas, haciendo click en *reportar* al pie de la misma. Esto abre una ventana sobre la cual podés seleccionar la opción "*Se necesita la intervención de un moderador*", y redactar una descripción de los motivos.

[image: Reporte personalizado: click en reportar + opción "se necesita la intervención de un moderador" + escribir la descripción + botón "Reportar pregunta"]

> pusieron algunas de mi preguntas en espera SIN motivo aparente

Vayamos al grano. Encontré 3 de tus preguntas en espera.
**¿Cuáles fueron las razones de cada voto?**

1. **[Error en php con consulta MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/44031/127)**

   Cuando vi esta pregunta, ya le habías encontrado la solución, y habías publicado [la respuesta a la misma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44034/127) a las 04:59, aclarando que era "*una simple Coma despues de la palabra conexion*". Al leer la respuesta, la voté +1 (actualmente el único voto positivo que tiene).

   Inmediatamente después, voté para cerrarla a las 05:54 como "*Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico.*", siendo el primero en hacerlo. Esto es lo que se debe hacer con todas las preguntas que tienen un problema de este estilo. No significa que estén mal, en absoluto, sólo significa que esta pregunta sólo se aplica en tu caso y que no es extensible al resto de los usuarios del sitio, y por ende, al estar resueltas, permanecer cerradas. No hay nada más que alguien pudiese agregar en esa pregunta, ya está resuelta y no tiene otra solución.

   Si te interesa leer más al respecto de este cierre y lo que opina la comunidad, podrás encontrarlo en la publicación [Agregar motivo de cierre: El problema no puede ser reproducido o error tipográfico](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/473/127).

   Incluso, tengo una propuesta para ser más laxos en este tipo de cierre, que no fue muy aceptada: [Excepciones al cierre por “un error tipográfico”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1300/127).
2. **[como visualisar una subconsulta mientras se ve la web sin apliacr submit](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/44178/127)**

   En esta es donde menos puedo explicar. Voté para ponerla *en espera* como "*no está claro lo que se pregunta*" porque no la entendí (sigo sin entenderla).

   Te cuento lo que analicé: leí que tenías una tabla en MySQL, y que querías asignarle un valor a una variable... Fui al código para ver qué estabas intentando hacer, y vi que estabas populando un elemento `<select>` con los resultados de una consulta de items con estado `ACTIVO` y precio `0`.

   ```php
       $sql = mysqli_query($conexion,'
       select * from sr_productos WHERE precio = 0 and estado = \'ACTIVO\'
       ');if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
       {echo"Elija Premio 2: <select required name='id_producto2' >\n";  
       print"<option value=''>-------------***************Elija una Opcion******************-----------</option>\n";
       while ($temp = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
       {
       print"<option value='".$temp["id"]."'>".$temp["nombre_esp"]."</option>\n";
       }
       echo"  </select>\n"; }else{ echo"No hay datos";  } mysqli_free_result($sql);
   ```

   Y luego en un comentario en el código:

   ```php
       <textarea><?php $id_producto2 ?></textarea><!--Aqui quiero que muestre el resultado del Select sr_productos instantaneamente osea que si seleciono NombreB deberia aparecer aqui 2 al instante-->
   ```

   Viendo ahora la respuesta que aceptaste, creo que esto debería haber sido lo principal de tu pregunta, como parte de la pregunta y no tan oculto en el código (fijate que la mayor parte de este comentario queda oculto por el scroll). Pero de la forma que lo interpreté, era que querías mostrar el resultado de una consulta en la base de datos dentro del textarea, viendo que `sr_productos` es el nombre de tu tabla, algo que ya estabas haciendo previamente, y que no tenía sentido que preguntes... No sé cuál es el resultado que querés mostrar.

   Voté +1 al comentario de [aldanux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6491/aldanux) que dice "*he leído 2 o 3 veces tu pregunta pero sigo sin entender lo que realmente quieres... si lo podrías editar y explicar mejor cual es tu objetivo... quizás alguien te podría ayudar (mejor)*" (me pasó lo mismo) y voté para poner en espera.

   En definitiva, si la respuesta aceptada es lo que buscabas, se está respondiendo a una pregunta de PHP con código de JavaScript/jQuery, sin que en ningún momento hayas mencionado que el código querías que se ejecute en el cliente y no en el servidor. Creo que eso sería también parte del motivo de mi voto. Pero creo que se ha malinterpretado lo que significa el voto, y lo comentaré más abajo.
3. [Relog regresivo a partir de consulta de un select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/45055/127)

   En esta pregunta voté para poner en espera al igual que al menos otras 7 personas, explicando el motivo de mi voto en un [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45055/relog-regresivo-a-partir-de-consulta-de-un-select#comment78415_45055) que dejé en la pregunta:

   > No entiendo. ¿Estás intentando que PHP actualice en tiempo real? el código PHP es ejecutado por el servidor al momento de obtener la página... ¿Cómo pensabas que se actualice?

   Este es el punto central, y no hace falta ver tan en detalle la pregunta. Tu intención es actualizar un reloj/contador/cuenta regresiva **en tiempo real**. Sin embargo, PHP se ejecuta en el servidor, y necesitaba que me aclares de qué forma pensabas que se actualice. Te aseguro que ante cualquier respuesta a mi comentario, hubiese retirado mi voto para poner en espera, y hubiese sido positivo que me respondas y poder ayudarte a terminar de moldear la pregunta. Relacionando ahora con la pregunta anterior, probablemente quieras que se ejecute en el cliente, siendo de nuevo una pregunta de JavaScript. Si es así, te recomiendo editarla aclarando este punto, eliminando todas las etiquetas y agregando [JavaScript], y con gusto votaré para reabrirla.

Ahora bien, me parece que estás malinterpretando lo que significa *poner en espera*. Cuando se pone en espera a una pregunta, el principal objetivo es que el autor pueda editar la pregunta para aclarar, por sobre todo, qué se está preguntando y qué se intentó hasta ahora. Esto no significa ni que tengas que saber cómo resolverlo, ni que sea insalvable. Todo lo contrario, es la forma de decirte que queremos responderte, pero aún no podemos, o que sería realmente un lío de respuestas que apuntan a lados diferentes sin un objetivo concreto.

Queremos que edites la pregunta, y al editarla pasará automáticamente a revisión. Si luego de la edición queda clara, tendrá los votos suficientes para reabrirse. Es decir, no es algo en contra de estas 3 preguntas que hiciste, sino más bien que se busca ayudarte de la mejor manera, incluso si eso implica pedirte más detalles antes de responderte.

Y, algo que me pareció gracioso (con todo respeto, se entiende el por qué de que lo hayas pensado)...

> mariano y muriano que por cierto deben ser la misma persona

No. Definitivamente no. De hecho, te confieso, me molestó un poco cuando vi que apareció alguien con un nick muy similar al mío :-\

---

**Mi opinión**. Creo que el hecho de que hayas publicado en meta, y estés intentando resolver los inconvenientes que hayas tenido es un signo totalmente positivo. Ojalá todos los usuarios hicieran esto, y por eso es que me tomé el tiempo para responderte (esperando que puedas ver la buena intención). Sin duda vas por buen camino, y me encantaría ver una edición que reabra tus 2 preguntas. Seguí publicando en Meta, que también sirve para preguntas del tipo "[*Quiero preguntar esto pero no sé cómo*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%C3%B3n-de-pregunta?sort=votes)", y de entrar al [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) para lo mismo (pero más informal). Además, leer otras preguntas también te puede ayudar a ver el formato que esperamos de preguntas y respuestas... es algo que a mí me encanta hacer.

Personalmente, voy a tomar lo que expresaste, intentando en el futuro ser más claro aún en los comentarios que dejo al revisar preguntas... Siempre estoy en la dicotomía entre "*comentario breve y al grano*" y "*demasiado extenso pero más claro*". Si hay algún comentario que creas que te podría haber ayudado mejor a entender estos puntos, no dudes en decírmelo.

Comment: esta muy bien pero, para mi, la parte central de esta respuesta es la parte que dice: _"...Cuando se pone en espera a una pregunta, el principal objetivo es que el autor pueda editar la pregunta para aclarar, por sobre todo, qué se está preguntando..."_ etc.. y se pierde bastante. Asi como esta, esta muy centrada en lo anegdotico

Comment: @EmanuelVe Yo creo que es necesaria la explicación. Yo no sabía.